# Defining using Type1 = Type2 globally

Tags: c#

I have

`using ListOfEntries = List<Entry>`

defined inside a namespace before a class where I am using it. I want to use that in another class. Is there anyway to define this using globally so I don't have to do this before every single class where I want to use that type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The `using` directive's scope is limited to the file where it is declared.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create global alias.

Workaround: Not same as alias, but you can create class inherited from `List<Entry>`:

```
public class ListOfEntries: List<Entry>
{

}
```

Comment: I tried that as the first solution only to discovered that in places where I explicitly used List<Entry>, I have to do an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
GenericList<T> : IList<T>, IBindingList, ICancelAddNew
{
 private IList<T> items = new List<T>;

  ...
}
```

---

> In implementing this class you can then talk to the database from inside this list class